# ¿Cómo programar un bucle con varias órdenes?

Tags: r, bucles, iteradores

Mi archivo de datos es el siguiente (df1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo hacer un script (que supongo que la manera más directa de programarlo será con un blucle) para calcular el intervalo entre la fecha de parto (fparto) y la fecha de inseminación (fechaIA) de la fila inmediatamente posterior, siempre y cuando el crotal sea el mismo.

Como ejemplo tomaré el animal de las filas 2 a la 4:

Debo crear una columna nueva (df1$intervalo), que en su fila 2 ponga el resultado de restar la fparto de la fila 2 y la fechaIA de la fila 3 (que dá 7 meses o 207 días), que en la fila 3 ponga el resultado de restar la fparto de la fila 3 y la fechaIA de la fila 4 (5 meses o 139 días) y que en la fila 4 ponga 0. Luego, el script debe ser capaz de identificar que la fila 5 corresponde a otro animal, debe empezar a hacer la misma operación tantas veces como ese animal aparezca, y así sucesivamente. ¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de hacerlo?

Pongo un ejemplo de como quisiera que quedara el df con el intervalo calculado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos armar una función que haga la diferencia entre `fparto` y la versión desplazada en un elemento de la columna `FechaIA`

```
restar_fechas <- function(grupo) {
  ln <- length(grupo$fparto)
  c(grupo$FechaIA[2:ln], NA)[1:ln] - grupo$fparto
}
```

Ahora simplemente separamos cada grupo de `crtotal` en elementos de una lista mediante `split()`

```
lista <- split(df1, df1$crtotal)
```

Y aplicamos esta función a cada grupo, mediante `lapply()` que no es más que bucle implícito, y finalmente, luego del `unlist()` tendremos los valores para la columna `intervalo`

```
df1$intervalo <- unlist(lapply(lista, restar_fechas))
```

Comment: El script calcula lo que necesito a la perfección pero tengo un problema y es que no escribe el resultado en la fila que quiero, cómo lo consigo?. Voy a editar la pregunta para que veas. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda